# Обращение к элементу фрагмента без поиска по id

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть вот такой рабочий пример кода

```
//  найти кнопку по id (тяжелая операция!!!!)
val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.roll_button)
rollButton.text = "Let's Roll" // change buttons text
```

Взято с курса гугла. В качестве альтернативы тяжелой операции поиска по id предлагается использовать прослойку data binding

Вопрос в том, что в другом курсе встретил вот такой рабочий код:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        button_login.setOnClickListener{ view : View ->
            view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_login_to_account)
        }
    }
```

суть в том, что обработчик вешается на кнопку button_login (это ее id), хотя нигде явно нет поиска по id.
Разве что, после вставки этого кода в импортах добавилось

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_login.*
```

Как тут произошел поиск кнопки ? Был какой то неявный поиск по id ?? Можно ли так писать в боевых проектах или это демонстрационный неоптимизированный пример ?

Спасибо

Comment: насколько я знаю синтетики под капотом ипользуют findViewById. в боевых проектах так и нужно писать

Comment: https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/kotlin-android-extensions-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-42ad43b029d7 читать

Comment: помимо DataBinding, есть ещё ViewBinding, который лучше и использовать вместо kotlin synthetic, так как с kotlin synthetic вы можете не тот layout импортировать и получить NPE на рантайме

Comment: @IR42 вот не разу у меня не было проблем с импортами. это вообще не проблема. а датабиндинг мне вообще не заходит кода больше и логику в лэйаут совать ну такое себе

Comment: @Cypher кажется я говорил про ViewBinding...

Comment: @IR42 а вот ViewBinding не пробовал не знаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Kotlin есть чудесная штука: *Kotlin Android Extensions*. Одной из прелестей этих функций есть "Синтетики (Synthetic)". Суть этой штуки в том, что в любой View где вы можете вызвать метод `findViewById()` вы можете напрямую обращаться ко View по их id.

Под капотом вызывается все тот же `findViewById()` и никакой магии в этом нет, но все это делается за вас, уменьшая пачку однотипного кода".

Вот хорошая [статья](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/) на эту тему.